# How to popup on top of parent view without affecting parent's size?

Tags: swiftui

The popup works. But when it pops up, it increases the parent view  height (parent height is smaller than pop-up and it's a requirement that parent to be smaller than pop-up). I want the popup to be an independent view. The popup should not affect the size of the parent or the views underneath it. How to do that? I don't wanna use `alert` as I have a long page to show as a popup which contains a list of items.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ParentView: View {


    @State private var WidgetSelectionShowState: Bool = false


    var body: some View {
        //Color.purple
        ZStack {

            Rectangle ()
                .fill(.blue)
                .zIndex(0) //
        Button ("show", action:  {

            withAnimation {
            WidgetSelectionShowState.toggle()
            }
                })

        if (WidgetSelectionShowState) {

            popupPage ()

        }
} .frame(width: 300, height: 100, alignment: .center)

    }
}


struct popupPage: View {


    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
        Text("This is a popup")


            Rectangle ()
                .fill(.green)
                .zIndex(0) //this is the layer order.

        }.transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .scale, removal: .opacity))
            . frame(width: 200, height: 500, alignment: .center )

}
}
```

[the output I'm expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM4rp.png)

Comment: Moving the frame modifier to the `Rectangle` in the `ParentView` fixes it.

Comment: Use `parent.overlay(child)` instead of `ZStack { parent child }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ZStack` will sets its frame based on the size of its children, so when you dynamically add or remove children, the size of the ZStack changes accordingly.

To do something different, you have a couple of options:

1. Attach the appearing/disappearing view to a view *above* the ZStack in the hierarchy whose size you don’t want to change. If this means you end up having another ZStack further up the view chain, that’ll have the same size change implications, but might be easier to manage.
2. Alternatively, implement the popover view using a `.overlay()` modifier. This will place the popup view on top of the original view just as ZStack does, but doesn’t affect the frame of the original.

   This approach brings its own layout issues, but as the original view will keep its position, they be easier to resolve.

An example of what the second approach might look like – just tweaking your supplied example code but not adjusting layout:

```
var body: some View {
  ZStack {
    Rectangle()
      .fill(.blue)
    Button("show", action:  {
      withAnimation {
        WidgetSelectionShowState.toggle()
      }
    })
  }
  .overlay(
    Group {
      if (WidgetSelectionShowState) {
        popupPage()
      }
    }
  )
}
```

I’m using `Group` here because you can’t place the `if` at the ‘top level’ of the overlay modifier’s argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I ended up liking both the approaches and used it in two places in the app.